# Remove empty string from a list of strings in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a list of strings:

```
q)l:("abc";"";"def";"");
```

How can we remove empty strings from the list l?

```
Desired Output:

("abc";"def")
```

My failed attempts:

```
q)l except ""
q)l except\: ""
q)l except 1#""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [enlist](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/enlist/) on the empty string will work:

```
q)l except enlist""
"abc"
"def"
```

In many cases, `1#` and `enlist` can be used interchangeably, as long as the list is not empty. Applying `1#` on an empty list will return an enlisted null of the empty list type provided:

```
q)1#`long$()
,0N
q)1#`symbol$()
,`
q)1#""
," "
```